# Is $Ax=b$ consistent all b in $R^3$ if A is a 3 x 5 matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

According to my textbook, the system $Ax=b$ is consistent for every $b$ if and only if the column vectors of A span $R^m$. Except I'm not given any information about A other than the fact that it is a 3x5 matrix. Do I need more information to solve this problem? I also figured out that the nullity had to be at least 3 and that the rank had to be at most 2, if that has something to do with it.

Comment: Oh and Cu,Cv, and Cw all = 0 where u, v, and w are linearly independent vectors

Comment: Wait, I might be on to something. If Ax=0 only has the trivial solution x=0 for those 3 cases (Au,Av,Aw) then does that mean the column vectors of A have to be linearly independent? By the way I mean Au,Av, and Aw instead of Cu,Cv, and Cw

Comment: You definitely have to have more information about rank of $A$. Otherwise you always can give an examples of matrices that are not consistent.

Comment: This is the exact question in case I left any important information out: Suppose A is a 3x5 matrix, that {s,t,u,v,w} is a linearly independent set of vectors in R^5, and that Au = 0, Av = 0, Aw = 0. Is Ax=b consistent for every choice of b in R^3?

Answer (score 1):

This means that dim range =3 and so dim null space is 2. So the row space must have dim 3 and this is the answer.